# For Immediate Variable Assignment, double colon or one?

Tags: makefile

In the GNU make manual, I see

```
Simply expanded variables are defined by lines using ‘:=’ or ‘::=’ (see 
Setting Variables). Both forms are equivalent in GNU make; however only the 
‘::=’ form is described by the POSIX standard (support for ‘::=’ was added to 
the POSIX standard in 2012, so older versions of make won’t accept this form
either).
```

I *thought* this meant that ::= was part of the standard, and := was vendor dependent. But I rarely see the double colon.

Which should I use for maximum portability?

Comment: I can't seem to find either `:=` or `::=` defined in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html), unless I'm looking in the wrong place, hopefully someone can weigh in on this. Either way if you really want *maximum* portability you should probably use neither, as some makes will only accept `=`.

Comment: Also, the author is understandably biased, but check out the first [Rule of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/).

Comment: I'm all in favour of using  a compatible make, but I was hoping other people had more experience with each version being allowed or not.

Comment: "Don't try to write portable Makefiles, use a portable make"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::=` syntax has been approved by the POSIX standards group, in 2011, along with `?=` and `+=`.  See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=330 for information on the process and why a new assignment operator was chosen instead of standardizing on `:=`.

I can't say which versions of make, other than GNU make, support this syntax yet.